# Распаковка 7z архива

Tags: c#, 7z

В приложении MVC скачиваю в папку проекта архив 7z. В наличие имеется 7z.exe и 7z.dll. Необходимо распаковать архив в папку в которую сохранила сам архив. Если кто может напишите примерчик, как распаковать архив 7z.